# pgfplots bar chart enlarge axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I would like to create a bar chart using tikz. I want it to look like that:

[image]

but when I added the data, I got something like that:
[image]

Is there a way to enlarge the x-axis over the textwidth or some other way to fix it? I would like the text to stay at this size.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
compat=newest,   
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},       
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,     
bar width=10pt,     
%         
point meta=rawy,     
%     
axis x line=bottom,     
axis y line=left,
ymajorgrids=true,     
grid style=dashed,
%     
ylabel=[MWh],     
ymin=0,      
scaled ticks=false,
tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
enlargelimits=auto,   
enlarge x limits=0.2, 
%          
symbolic x coords ={2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025,2026,2027,2028,2029,2030,2031,2032,2033,2034,2035,2036},     
%x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=north east},  
xtick distance=1,
/pgf/number format/.cd,        
use comma,         
1000 sep={.}
]
\addplot[fill=Grey] coordinates {   
(2021,232)              
(2022,224)       
(2023,216)         
(2024,208 )         
(2025, 200)
(2026,192)
(2027,184)
(2028,176) 
(2029,168) 
(2030,160)
(2031, 152)
(2032,144)
(2033,136) 
(2034, 128)
(2035,120) 
(2036,112)
};   
\addplot[fill=LightBlue] coordinates {      
(2021,198) 
(2022,193)                   
(2023,188)           
(2024,182) 
(2025,177)   
(2026,172) 
(2027,167)
(2028,162) 
(2029,157) 
(2030,152)
(2031,147)
(2032,142)
(2033,137) 
(2034, 132)
(2035,127) 
(2036, 122 )      
};   
\addplot[fill=Blue] coordinates {    
(2021,122)                
(2022,134)     
(2023,147)           
(2024,160) 
(2025,172)  
(2026,185) 
(2027,198)
(2028,210) 
(2029,223) 
(2030, 236)
(2031, 248)
(2032,261)
(2033,274) 
(2034, 287)
(2035,299) 
(2036,312)      
};   
\addplot[fill=DarkBlue] coordinates {          
(2021,300)              
(2022,317)     
(2023,335)           
(2024,353) 
(2025,370)    
(2026,388)
(2027,405)
(2028, 423) 
(2029, 441) 
(2030,458)
(2031, 476)
(2032, 493)
(2033,511) 
(2034,528)
(2035, 546) 
(2036,564)   
};   
\legend{Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, Option 4}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm sorry, if the question has been asked before, I just couldn't find anything that fit my answer.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `width=0.9\textwidth` and/or `height=<length>` in the `axis` options. If you only specify one the aspect ratio remains the same. Quite possibly a duplicate can be found, if not me (or whoever else feels like doing so) can add an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've answered something along the same lines before, but couldn't find it now, so here goes.

As mentioned in my comment, you use the `width` and `height` keys in the `axis` options to set the approximate<sup>1</sup> size of the diagram.

Obviously, whether all your bars actually fit inside the available space, depends on a few things:

- how wide the axis is (set by `width=<length>`)
- how many bars you have
- the width of the bars (set by `bar width=<length>`)
- the space between the bars (set by the argument to `ybar`, e.g. `ybar=1pt`)

The exact choices for these will depend on how your document is set up, how wide the text block is. The choices made in the example below is for a standard `article` with A4 paper.

You say you want the text to remain the same size, and presumably that includes the xticklabels. With a standard `article` there is not enough room to have all the ticklabels horizontally. If your document has a wider text block there may be room. I guess the options are to either not print all the labels (shown below), or rotate the labels. If you prefer that option, uncomment the lines with `xtick distance=1` and `x tick label style={..}`. You'll also need to move the legend down a bit.

Note that when you have a `]` in a value in the option list, as in `ylabel=[MWh]`, you need to wrap the value in braces, otherwise `pgfplots` sees the `]` as the closing bracket for the `axis` options, so everything after it is basically ignored. I.e., do `ylabel={[MWh]}`.

I also removed the symbolic coords, I don't really see the need for them here, when you have evenly spaced numerical x-values.

---

<sup>1</sup>: `pgfplots` doesn't calculate an exact size of the entire diagram, including all labels. It simply allocates a fixed amount of space, 45pt, for the labels. Hence, if you set `width=345pt`, what `pgfplots` actually does is to set the size of the axis box alone (not including labels) to 300pt, and the total width is 300pt + whatever amount of space the labels occupy. If you set `scale only axis`, then the `width`/`height` apply to the axis box alone.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % or whatever version you have
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth,    % set width
height=0.55\textwidth, % and height
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},       
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar=0.5pt, % reduce space between bars
bar width=3pt,   % they were too wide
%         
point meta=rawy,     
%     
axis x line=bottom,     
axis y line=left,
ymajorgrids=true,     
grid style=dashed,
%     
ylabel={[MWh]}, % wrap in {} when you have []
ymin=0,      
scaled ticks=false,
enlarge x limits={abs=0.6}, 
%% if you want xtick distance=1 you either need a wider textblock, or rotate the ticklabels as you've done before
%x tick label style={rotate=30,anchor=north east},  
% xtick distance=1,
/pgf/number format/.cd,        
use comma,         
1000 sep={.}
]
\addplot[fill=Grey] coordinates {   
(2021,232)              
(2022,224)       
(2023,216)         
(2024,208 )         
(2025, 200)
(2026,192)
(2027,184)
(2028,176) 
(2029,168) 
(2030,160)
(2031, 152)
(2032,144)
(2033,136) 
(2034, 128)
(2035,120) 
(2036,112)
};   
\addplot[fill=LightBlue] coordinates {      
(2021,198) 
(2022,193)                   
(2023,188)           
(2024,182) 
(2025,177)   
(2026,172) 
(2027,167)
(2028,162) 
(2029,157) 
(2030,152)
(2031,147)
(2032,142)
(2033,137) 
(2034, 132)
(2035,127) 
(2036, 122 )      
};   
\addplot[fill=Blue] coordinates {    
(2021,122)                
(2022,134)     
(2023,147)           
(2024,160) 
(2025,172)  
(2026,185) 
(2027,198)
(2028,210) 
(2029,223) 
(2030, 236)
(2031, 248)
(2032,261)
(2033,274) 
(2034, 287)
(2035,299) 
(2036,312)      
};   
\addplot[fill=DarkBlue] coordinates {          
(2021,300)              
(2022,317)     
(2023,335)           
(2024,353) 
(2025,370)    
(2026,388)
(2027,405)
(2028, 423) 
(2029, 441) 
(2030,458)
(2031, 476)
(2032, 493)
(2033,511) 
(2034,528)
(2035, 546) 
(2036,564)   
};   
\legend{Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, Option 4}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right. This is a quite common question here. I will close the question as duplicate where I state some of my answers to similar questions. Of course feel free to extend the list when you find yours ;)

Comment: thanks a lot, that works perfect! :)